# SwiftUI - making a reusable custom TextField for different types of input

Tags: ios, swiftui

Currently I'm working on a SwiftUI project that requires different types of text input such as phone number, amount, email, ID number, etc. I have been looking over the internet for the past couple of days to see what other developers came up with to get some inspiration but I couldn't find anything useful for my case. At the end, I came up with the following idea:

```
struct CoreTextField<Value, InputFormatter: FormatterProtocol>: View where InputFormatter.Input == Value {

    private var text: State<String>
    private var value: Binding<Value>
    private let formatter: InputFormatter

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

FormatterProtocol has one associated type, Input, which is the value that the formatter is expected to convert into a String and produce a value from a given String. The textfield keeps its internal text state, which is formatted as the user types in something and updated with using the onChange modifier. After the textfield doesn't have focus, the actual value expected is communicated back via the value Binding. Other textfields for different types of input can be derived by using this structure and implementing a formatter for the task at hand. I'm wondering if there are better alternatives or things that can be improved.

Thanks in advance